# What is this: res://C:\WINDOWS\system32\shdoclc.dll/http_400.htm#?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, windows-xp

I am running Windows XP with IE6 and doing some web stuff but for some reason, when I submit a page, I am getting a HTTP 400 Bad Request

> The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

When I do a right-mouse click properties, the URL value is:

```
res://C:\WINDOWS\system32\shdoclc.dll/http_400.htm#
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the page that shows up when you get a 400 Error. Is just like when you define your custom error pages on IIS.

As for your problem, can you show us your page/action you're trying to do? I think there's the problem not in that page.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer supports the 'res' protocol handler. This is similar to the 'http', 'https', 'ftp', etc. protocol handlers, except that it assumes that the entity is a Windows resource. Resources are binary objects embedded in Win32 executable files (EXE and DLL files, for example).

This one is just the path to the error placeholder text for an HTTP 400 error. It's kept in `shdoclc.dll`.

What it might mean is that you issued an HTTP `GET` when the application only responds to `POST` requests, or that your request was badly formed.

At this point, you need to look at the actual network traffic. Use Netmon or Wireshark or similar. And read RFC2616.